# MySQL Search Results Using Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am building a superhero database. I would like to join each individual table together so that the user can search for anything rather than having to do an INNER JOIN every time the user performs a query.

For instance, a user could search for the comic series that the superhero came from and all you would have to do is change the SELECT and the WHERE clause.

This returns a good result when searching for a superhero's power:

```
SELECT sh.heroName, pwr.name FROM superhero sh
INNER JOIN superheroPower sh_pwr ON sh.id = sh_pwr.superheroID
INNER JOIN power pwr ON sh_pwr.powerID = pwr.id
WHERE sh.heroName = 'Superman';
```

This returns an empty set:

```
SELECT sh.heroName, pwr.name FROM superhero sh
INNER JOIN superheroPower sh_pwr ON sh.id = sh_pwr.superheroID
INNER JOIN power pwr ON sh_pwr.powerID = pwr.id
INNER JOIN superheroAffiliation sh_aff ON sh.id = sh_aff.superheroID 
INNER JOIN affiliation aff ON sh_aff.affiliationID = aff.id
INNER JOIN superheroComic sh_c ON sh.id = sh_c.superheroID
INNER JOIN comic c ON sh_c.comicID = c.id
INNER JOIN publisher pub ON c.publisherID = pub.id
INNER JOIN comicAuthor c_a ON c.id = c_a.comicID
INNER JOIN author a ON c_a.authorID = a.id
WHERE sh.heroName = 'Superman';
```

Is there a way to search the database with all of the tables already INNER JOINed together? Should I be doing a LEFT JOIN or a different type of JOIN instead?

Comment: "all the tables aready inner joined"? Yes... define a view that has all the joins in it. `select from view where foo=bar`

Comment: @MarcB , Hi can you please tell us why view would be better than all Inner joins in a query?

Comment: it isn't. it just saves you from having to type out all of that again. if you don't want to use joins, then don't normalize your table, and suffer all of the consequences that come from that.

Answer (score 1):

If there were no NULLs anywhere (as in, everyone of those links in joins always has something on the other side), that would work.

However, because it is an INNER any cases where one side of the join does not have results will eliminate the rows (non matching rows do not show up in an INNER join).

So to answer your direct question, assuming the key you care about is heroName, you should start from superhero and left join everything else on.  If you want to be able to use any field as the key, you should be using full outer on all the joins.